# Text Aligned in Friggeri CV Template Sections

Tags: positioning, text, cv, friggeri-cv

I'm having trouble with text alignment in the Contact section of the [Friggeri CV Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/friggeri-cv-template/hmnchbfmjgqh). I'd like the long e-mail addresses or websites names to be aligned properly *to the right* as everything else under the 'contact' section. Do you have any suggestions on how to get this done?

I tried to change parameters in the `geometry` package use the `ragged2e` package, and modify the `aside` environment but nothing worked. Here's the class `cv-style` used

```
% -- Encoding UTF-8 without BOM

\ProvidesClass{cv-style}[2015/02/27 CV class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\DeclareOption{espanol}{\def\@cv@espanol{}}
\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}%
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Colors %
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{333333}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{999999}

\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{66D9EE}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{FA2772}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FE9720}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{A7E22E}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{9358FE}
\definecolor{aquamarine}{HTML}{36AF90}

\definecolor{date}{HTML}{A4A4A4}

\ifdefined\@cv@print
  \colorlet{blue}{gray}
  \colorlet{red}{gray}
  \colorlet{orange}{gray}
  \colorlet{green}{gray}
  \colorlet{purple}{gray}
  \colorlet{aquamarine}{gray}
  \colorlet{fillheader}{white}
  \colorlet{header}{gray}
\else
  \colorlet{fillheader}{gray}
  \colorlet{header}{white}
\fi
\colorlet{textcolor}{gray}
\colorlet{headercolor}{gray}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Fonts %
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}

\newfontfamily\bodyfont{Computer 
 Modern}
\newfontfamily\bodyfontit{Computer Modern}
\newfontfamily\thinfont{Computer Modern}
\newfontfamily\headingfont{Computer Modern}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Computer Modern}

\newcommand{\italica}[1]{%
    {\color{gray}\bodyfontit #1}%
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Header %
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\header}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=fillheader, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=2cm] (box) at (current page.north){};
    \node [anchor=center] (name) at (box) {%
      \fontsize{40pt}{65pt}\color{header}%
      {\thinfont #1}{\bodyfont  #2}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{1cm}
  \vspace{-2\parskip}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Last updated command %
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}

\newcommand{\sethyphenation}[3][]{%
  \sbox0{\begin{otherlanguage}[#1]{#2}
    \hyphenation{#3}\end{otherlanguage}}}
%\sethyphenation[<options>]{<language>}{<list of words separated by spaces>}

\ifdefined\@cv@espanol
  \setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
  \def\lastupdatedtext{Última Actualización el}
\else
  \setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
  \def\lastupdatedtext{Last Updated on}
\fi

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{0.01\paperwidth}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{0.01\paperwidth}

\newcommand{\lastupdated}{ 
  \begin{textblock}{10}(11.3, 0.05)
    \raggedleft
    \fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\color{date}\thinfont 
    \lastupdatedtext{} \today
  \end{textblock}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Structure %
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{parskip}

\newcounter{colorCounter}
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
  {%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        blue\or%
        red\or%
        orange\or%
        green\or%
        purple\or%
        aquamarine\else%
        headercolor\fi%
    } #1#2#3%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  {\par\vspace{\parskip}
  {%
    \LARGE\headingfont\color{headercolor}%
    \@sectioncolor #1%
  }
  \par\vspace{\parskip}}
}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[2]{
  \par\vspace{.5\parskip}%
  \Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} #2%
  \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
}

\newcommand{\jobtitle}[1]{%
    {\color{gray}\bodyfontit #1}%
}

\pagestyle{empty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% List environment %
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{12.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Side block %
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\newenvironment{aside}{%
  \let\oldsection\section
  \renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} ##1}
  }
  \begin{textblock}{3.6}(1, 1.87)
  \begin{flushright}
  \obeycr
}{%
  \restorecr
  \end{flushright}
  \end{textblock}
  \let\section\oldsection
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Other tweaks %
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[left=5.6cm,top=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle=CV/Resume \textbar{} Alejandro Pérez Londoño,
    pdfauthor=Alejandro Pérez Londoño,
    pdfsubject=CV/Resume%
    }
```

And here's the MWE:

```
% -- Encoding UTF-8 without BOM
% -- XeLaTeX => PDF (BIBER)
\documentclass{cv-style}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}


\begin{document}
\header{My}{Name}
\begin{aside}
%
\section{contact}
123 Broadway
City, State 050022
Country
~
+0 (000) 111 1111
+0 (000) 111 1112
~
myemailistoolong@gmail.com
mywebsitetoo.wordpress.com
%
\end{aside}
%
\section{skills}
  \vspace{-0.2cm}

Skill 1, skill 2, skill 3, skill 4, skill 5.

\section{education}
\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2010--2011}
{M.Sc. {\normalfont in Economics [Grade]}}
{University}
{\vspace{-0.3cm}}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2004--2009}
{B.Eng. {\normalfont in Engineering Management [Grade]}}
{University}
{(Emphasis in ...)}
%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the class file in this line

```
\RequirePackage[left=5.6cm,top=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
```

there is only 5.6cm reserved in the left margin for your datas added with environment `aside`. For your email adress that is too small.

So you have to redefine three things:

1. bigger left margin, for example with `\geometry{left=7cm}`. Please see that I also added for testing purpose option `showframe` for `geometry` to visualize typing area and margins ...
2. correct/change the length for the text in `aside` with changing `3.6` to `5` in the line

   ```
   \begin{textblock}{5}(1, 1.87) % <=================================== 3.6 -> 5
   ```
3. correct used length of `12.8cm` to now needed `10.8cm` in command `\entry` in the line

   ```
   #1&\parbox[t]{10.8cm}{% <============================================= 12.8cm --> 10.8cm
   ```

So with the complete code

```
% -- Encoding UTF-8 without BOM
% -- XeLaTeX => PDF (BIBER)
\documentclass{cv-style}

\renewenvironment{aside}{% <============================================
  \let\oldsection\section
  \renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} ##1}
  }
  \begin{textblock}{5}(1, 1.87) % <=================================== 3.6 -> 5
  \begin{flushright}
  \obeycr
}{%
  \restorecr
  \end{flushright}
  \end{textblock}
  \let\section\oldsection
}

\renewcommand{\entry}[4]{% <============================================
  #1&\parbox[t]{10.8cm}{% <============================================= 12.8cm --> 10.8cm
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}


\geometry{%
  showframe, % <================ only to visualize typing area & margins
  left=7cm   % <============================= bigger space on right side 5.6cm --> 7cm
}


\begin{document}

\header{My}{Name}
\begin{aside}
%
\section{contact}
123 Broadway
City, State 050022
Country
~
+0 (000) 111 1111
+0 (000) 111 1112
~
myemailistoolong@gmail.com
mywebsitetoo.wordpress.com
%
\end{aside}
%
\section{skills}
  \vspace{-0.2cm}

Skill 1, skill 2, skill 3, skill 4, skill 5.

\section{education}
\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2010--2011}
{M.Sc. {\normalfont in Economics [Grade]}}
{University}
{\vspace{-0.3cm}}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2004--2009}
{B.Eng. {\normalfont in Engineering Management [Grade]}}
{University}
{(Emphasis in ...)}
%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}


\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: resulting pdf]

BTW: the template is not very good, all that length you have manualy to change should be calculated and not be used as fixed values ... Could be you have to change more numbers ...