# Enable enumerate or itemize in custom env

Tags: xetex, environments, enumerate, friggeri-cv

I have an `aside` environment from a template.

```
\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}                        
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}                                   
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}                                    
\newenvironment{aside}{%                                          
  \let\oldsection\section                                         
  \renewcommand{\section}[1]{                                     
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{dgreen} ##1}       
  }                                                               
  \begin{textblock}{3.6}(2.0, 0.55)                               
  \begin{flushright}
  \obeycr
}{%
  \restorecr                                                      
  \end{flushright}                                                
  \end{textblock}
  \let\section\oldsection                                         
}
```

I set this region up with the following structure:

```
\begin{aside}
\section{RegionA}
~
\end{aside}
```

However, if I add in `enumerate` or `itemize`, LaTeX does not compile:

```
\begin{aside}
\section{RegionA}
\begin{enumerate}
\item foo
\end{enumerate}
\end{aside}
```

---

The compilation fails with the following error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.75 \begin{enumerate}
```

And I am wondering how to modify this `aside` environment for usage with `enumerate`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your `aside` class is incomplete. Please provide a [minimal but complete example document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (class file plus document) that reproduces the error you encounter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using class `friggeri-cv` or a slightly changed one `cv-style`, both using same environment `aside` (see also this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/492213/16550)).

I took the mwe from the cited question and changed it a little bit. The culprit here is that you try to insert in an place where text is right-justified an per se left-justified text. That would give an pretty ugly result! Please see this relevant code:

```
\begin{aside}
%
\section{contact}
123 Broadway
City, State 050022
Country
~
+0 (000) 111 1111
+0 (000) 111 1112
~
myemail@gmail.com
myweb.wordpress.com

%
\section{RegionA}
~
1. foo
2. bar
~
\section{RegionB}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item foo
  \item bar
\end{enumerate}
\end{aside}
```

In section RegionA I now added your enumeration manually, that means **without using environment** `enumerate`! In section RegionB I use `enumerate` resulting in  3 error messages you also got.

See the following complete compiling code with one error message

```
\documentclass{cv-style}


\begin{document}

\header{My}{Name}
\begin{aside}
%
\section{contact}
123 Broadway
City, State 050022
Country
~
+0 (000) 111 1111
+0 (000) 111 1112
~
myemail@gmail.com
myweb.wordpress.com

%
\section{RegionA}
~
1. foo
2. bar
~
\section{RegionB}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item foo
  \item bar
\end{enumerate}
\end{aside}
%
\section{skills}
  \vspace{-0.2cm}

Skill 1, skill 2, skill 3, skill 4, skill 5.

\section{education}
\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2010--2011}
{M.Sc. {\normalfont in Economics [Grade]}}
{University}
{\vspace{-0.3cm}}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2004--2009}
{B.Eng. {\normalfont in Engineering Management [Grade]}}
{University}
{(Emphasis in ...)}
%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}


\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

The RegionA part looks okay and fits the other layout (building a vertical line on the right in the first column and a vertical line for the text starting in the right column.

The **RegionB part looks ugly**, because it does not fit the used layout. Flushed left text in an flushed right layout does not look good, **simply omit that**. See the red arrow in the screenshot marked with a flash!

The content of environment `aside` is not prepared to handle `enumerate` or `itemize`, it is an simple tool proposed to have manually added text only.

So to omit the error messages simply use the method shown in RegionA and delete wrong RegionB!

BTW: Rethink your principal layout of your CV if you really need an itemized or enumerated list in that first small column. Lists should be placed in the second column in this layout design IMHO.

Comment: Oh, ok.  So this second document makes use of a different implementation of aside?

Comment: @donlan no, environment `aside` is same in both classes. Test it with your used class and please edit your question and add there which class you use. Because I answered the cited question it was easier for me to use the other class (already everthing copied on my computer and not having to copy friggeri-cv etc.)

Comment: Gotcha. just didn’t see any difference between how enumerate was called between the two examples.